# How to debug the logstash file plugin

Tags: logging, logstash

Is it possible to log actions of the logstash file plugin? (i.e. what files it tries to send, what errors happen, etc)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In new version stdout  format changed

```
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
```

Comment: I also want to know how to show only Logstash parse errors, like _jsonparsefailure

Answer (score 15):

If you want to debug the process itself you may run it like this

```
/opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f yourconf.conf -v --debug --verbose
```

**NOTE:** According to @neeraj-gupta using `--debug` and `--verbose` at the same time may cause a problem when trying to see debug logs of cloudwatch and using only `--debug` is enough.

So realistically something like this is more apt:

```
/opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f yourconf.conf --debug
```

Answer (score 5):

*** * * This method of debugging is now deprecated - see Max's answer above! * * ***

Try adding a [stdout](http://logstash.net/docs/1.2.1/outputs/stdout) output with debug set to true.  You should be able to see the entire event object and errors / warnings in your logstash [--log](http://logstash.net/docs/1.2.1/flags) or stdout.

```
input {
   file {
      ...
   }
}
output {
   stdout {
      debug => true
   }
   ...
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: debug parameter is deprecated

Comment: debug => true doesn't work any more (tested on v2.3).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can see what files it tries to send, what errors happening through the output section by applying:

```
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
```

Codec is responsible for giving output. So, here it outputs your event data using the ruby "awesome_print" library.