# Interpret locations from Keen.io JSON file in logstash filter

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, keen-io

I'm trying to parse a JSON file from Keen.io with logstash into elasticsearch. The location and timestamp are stored in parameters like this:

```
{
  "result":
  [
    {
      "keen":
      {
        "timestamp": "2014-12-02T12:23:51.000Z",
        "created_at": "2014-12-01T23:25:31.396Z",
        "id": "XXXX",
        "location":
        {
          "coordinates": [-95.8, 36.1]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My filter currently looks like this:

```
input {
  file {
    path => ["test.json"]
    start_position => beginning
    type => json
  }
}

filter {
  json {
    source => message
    remove_field => message
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

How can I parse the "timestamp" and "location" fields so they are used for the @timestamp and @geoip.coordinates in Elasticsearch?

Update:
I've tried variations of this with no luck. The documentation is very basic - am I misunderstanding how to reference the JSON fields? Is there a way of adding debug output to help? I tried [How to debug the logstash file plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086404/how-to-debug-the-logstash-file-plugin) and [Print a string to stdout using Logstash 1.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452239/print-a-string-to-stdout-using-logstash-1-4) but neither works.

```
filter {
  json {
    source => message
    remove_field => message
  }
  if ("[result][0][keen][created_at]") {
    date {
      add_field => [ "[timestamp]", "[result][0][keen][created_at]" ]
      remove_field => "[result][0][keen][created_at]"
    }
  }
```

Update 2:

Date is working now, still need to get location working.

```
filter {
  json {
    source => message
    remove_field => message
    add_tag => ["valid_json"]
  }
  if ("valid_json") {
    if ("[result][0][keen][created_at]") {
      date {
        match => [ "[result][0][keen][created_at]", "ISO8601" ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that `add_field` is the right one, you'd need `update_field` because the timestamp field already exists. Anyhow, does it jump into the `if (...)` part at all? Add a tag somewhere in there to find out.

Comment: But `update_field` doesn't exist? Good idea on the tag, was wondering what they were for.

Comment: What you want is the `match` attribute of the `date` filter, like `filter {
  date {
    match => [ "[result][0][keen][created_at]", "MMM dd YYYY HH:mm:ss" ]
  }
}`

Comment: http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/mutate#update is the one I meant, it is only available via the `mutate` filter. So, store the value in a temporary and then update it using that filter. Concerning the tags, I'd regularly set a tag like `valid_json` in the `json` filter and then check for this tag to decide further processing. I'd also use the else branch to mark this log entry as clearly invalid, as it suggests there's a programming error somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keen.io's "created_at" field is stored in [ISO 8601 format](https://keen.io/docs/event-data-modeling/event-data-intro/#iso-8601-format) and so can easily be parsed by the date filter. Lat/long co-ordinates can be set by copying Keen.io's existing co-ordinates into logstash's geoip.coordinates array.

```
input {
  file {
    path => ["data.json"]
    start_position => beginning
    type => json
  }
}

filter {
  json {
    source => message
    remove_field => message
    add_tag => ["valid_json"]
  }
  if ("valid_json") {
    if ("[result][0][keen][created_at]") {
      date {
        # Set @timestamp to Keen.io's "created_at" field
        match => [ "[result][0][keen][created_at]", "ISO8601" ]
      }
    }
    if ("[result][0][keen][location][coordinates]") {
      mutate {
        # Copy existing co-orndiates into geoip.coordinates array
        add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[result][0][keen][location][coordinates][0]}" ]
        add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[result][0][keen][location][coordinates][1]}" ]
        remove_field => "[result][0][keen][location][coordinates]"
      }
    }
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```